# Resource name invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net

on my page `ProductManagement.aspx` i have a literal:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" meta:resourcekey="TabAddProduct" />
```

in my resource file i want to set the value to `"Product toevoegen"`
in my `ProductManagement.aspx.resx` i filled in this:

[image]

but on the page it shows empty

can someone help me with my error?

I tried it without the `.Text` but it still shows empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

While creating a resource file it was added in the:

**App_GlobalResources** folder

Instead it needed to be in the:

**App_LocalResources** folder.....